# Getting managedObjectContext from Document-based app

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I just created a Document-based app and now I want to show my Data in a Table View. To do so, I created a tableViewController Class but I need to get the managedObjectContext... But I don't know how to do it, I always get null...

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSApp delegate] managedObjectContext];
```

or

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] currentDocument] managedObjectContext];
```

But when I try to get the managedObjectContext directly in my Document.m (subclass of NSPersistentDocument) it's never null.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help!

Nick